# how to get list of quart jobs in spring and quartz scheduler

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz scheduler with spring application

> jobs triggered

and now i need to display list of jobs and their fired time

Comment: i think whenever any job is fired then u have to update db table for tracking record because in real time for every day we can't track it it must be saved some where to pick it up and show it.

Comment: thank you for your response,

can we use job Listener for listen jobs can we implement any thing based on this can you give me some clarity

Comment: yes, for you can have a job listener which will save the type of job ,name of job and last fired time , but yes in future it will be having too may records at some instant of time.

Comment: thank you,i have one case just need to show jobs details.can you give me any reference or example for job listener

Comment: please refer  1.)www.mkyong.com/java/quartz-joblistener-example  2.)http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/dev-guidance.html

Comment: plz do let me know if it worked for you or not.